# saving data in HTML and javascript

Tags: javascript, html, save

I feel like this is a complicated topic, I searched everywhere and can't seem to find a good method to save data from users. I'm making an incremental and want people to be able to leave their browsers and have their data saved when they come back. Anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: You'll need some type of a "place" to store the data, and that is most often a database. Your ISP probably provides a database and you can learn a bit of javascript, jQuery ajax and php. Definitely not trivial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's pretty easy though I guess it might depend on your app. Easiest way is through using HTML5 localStorage which is built in permanent storage for modern browsers that can be manipulated easily with javascript. A good article [here](http://diveintohtml5.info/storage.html).  If you are concerned about browsers that don't support localStorage then you can use one of the libraries that offers cookie fallback such as [jStorage](http://www.jstorage.info) which happens to have a form example.

Comment: I've been tossing up the idea of trying to learn HTML 5 for a while, i know why i should, but is it really worth it for one guy that doesn't really expect much out of his website?

Comment: Thanks, you were a huge help.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're going to need an SQL database. I'd recommend learning SQL, and learning a server-side programming language like PHP or ASP to automatically access the database. There is a lot to cover. I learned originally using w3schools, and have supplemented my education since then. w3schools an okay (not good, just okay) reference, but I wouldn't really recommend learning entirely from it. I'd recommend learning from youtube tutorials to get demonstrations and reading the manual for your server-side language.

Comment: Ok, so does using MySQL mean i need a whole new computer as a database? or are there providers? or is there another way withought MySQL?

Comment: You need a website with an SQL database. So you need to get hosting with enough memory to store that data. I assumed you had a website already because you said people were on "their browsers." You can download XAMPP or WAMP to test and learn SQL and PHP.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to look into [HTML5 Web Storage](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp). The localStorage object can be used to store data (strings) in the user's browser (not server-side). HTML5 Web Storage is [widely supported in modern browsers](http://caniuse.com/#search=web%20storage).
If you need the data server-side as well, cookies may be a good choice for small amounts of data.
If you have large amounts of structured data and wide browser support is not crucial, you should check out [HTML5 IndexedDB](http://www.w3.org/TR/IndexedDB/).

Comment: I will defenetly look into this as well as the rest of HTML 5, it defenetly has a lot of good uses.